# Show $\int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^{xy}dxdy = -\int_0^1 t^t \ln(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have to show $\int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^{xy}dxdy = -\int_0^1 t^t \ln(t)dt$ and I am stucked. I tried the following things

- I wrote $(xy)^{xy} = e^{xy\ln(xy)}$ as the exponential series which ended up with the integrals
  $\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^ky^k \ln(xy)^k dxdy$ but I could not proceed from here
- I tried to use the transformation formula with the map $(t_1,t_2) \mapsto (t_1t_2, t_2^{-1})$ and  I could proceed again.

There is also hint, which is easy to prove but I do not know how to use it:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1  f(y_1^{\beta_{11}}y_2^{\beta_{12}},y_1^{\beta_{21}}y_2^{\beta_{22}}) dy_1dy_2 = \det A \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f(x_1,x_2) x_1^{\alpha_{11}+\alpha_{21}-1}x_2^{\alpha_{12}+\alpha_{22}-1}dx_1dx_2,$$

where $A=(\alpha_{ij})$ is the inverse matrix to $B=(\beta_{ij})$ (it is assumed that $B$ is invertible)

Comment: This looks closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543829/seemingly-impossible-double-integral-reduction.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(y_1^{\beta_{11}}y_2^{\beta_{12}},y_1^{\beta_{21}}y_2^{\beta_{22}})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=xy$.  Then,

$$\int_0^1 (xy)^{xy}\,dx=\int_0^y t^t\,\frac1y \,dt$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^{xy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac1y t^t\,dt\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^1 t^t\int_t^1 \frac1y\,dy\,dt\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 t^t\log(t)\,dt
\end{align}$$

as expected!